# my android app's database is cleared abnormally

Tags: android, sqlite

One of my app's users, tells my app's database is cleared, which is an abnormal accident. Can someone tell me what programming reason maybe cause the accident in android.

Comment: How can we know? there are millions of *abnormal accidents*.

Comment: clear application's cache leads this type of error

Answer (score 1):

**Possible Reason:**

Maybe he clicked on the clear data from app setting application.
Whenever user will tap In android Settings> applications> Manage application> application> clear data on that button every app data will be lost.

[image]

Apps sometimes can misbehave. Before you go reaching for that task killer (don't do it!) here's something else to try. Above is the screen you'll see if you go to Settings>Applications>Manage appliations and tap on an app. You've got a bunch of buttons and numbers. The top buttons are pretty self-explanatory -- force stop makes an app quit. Uninstall either uninstalls an app -- or if it's permanently loaded onto the phone (like the Android Market should be), you'll have the option to uninstall updates.

But when we have a misbehaving app, first thing we'll try is to clear the cache. That wipes out temporary files that might be causing trouble. Your app's still there, as are all your settings.

**Clearing data is a little more drastic, basically giving you a clean installation of the app, with all of your settings and log-ins returned to zero. It's pretty much the same as uninstalling and reinstalling, just quicker.**

Comment: No useful answer. Absolutely I do not mean this.

Comment: @Longwayto From your above explanation this is the only possible answer anyone can think. You should explain your problem a bit more. So that I can help you.